# How to drop function if it already exist in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have defined custom function in mysql (using Rails 3 btw), beginning of the definition was like that

```
CREATE FUNCTION SOURCE_NAME(source INT(10))
```

This function works fine but now i need to drop it with mysql `drop function` statement.

This is the list of what i've tried already, none works, they only raise exceptions:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS SOURCE_NAME;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS SOURCE_NAME
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS SOURCE_NAME();
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS SOURCE_NAME()
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS 'SOURCE_NAME'
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS 'SOURCE_NAME';
```

and i have no idea what to do next, every example i find online looks different...

Comment: What exceptions do you get?

Comment: those are the ones that all look the same, similar to those i posted in comment under your answer, just pointing to a different things, sometimes '()' or '();'

Comment: My guess is that you do not have "drop" privileges on the database, somehow.

Answer (score 4):

It works in Rails 3. Try the following code inside `self.up` of your migration file

```
execute <<-SQL
   DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS function_name;
SQL
```